# Process Builder vs Workflow - Scheduled Actions - Created OR Edited

Tags: workflow, process-builder, scheduled

*I cannot find documentation to verify this.*

Is it still the case that you CANNOT do a **Scheduled Action** in Process Builder UNLESS it is on a "record being created" PB?

I need to do Scheduled Actions when a record is EDITED, so at the moment, I'm going to use **Workflows** out of necessity, but these will literally be the ONLY Workflows in our system.

I would prefer them to be in Process Builder where all of our other logic-flows are happening.  *Without going to actual Apex, of course.*

Thanks.

[image: Process Builder - Scheduled Actions only on "Created"?]

Answer (score 3):

Process Builder allows scheduled actions under either of two conditions, outlined in [Specify When Your Actions Should Execute with a Schedule](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_action_schedule.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=208.18):

> - The process starts only when a record is created (1).
> - The process starts when a record is created or edited (2), and the associated criteria node executes actions only when specified changes
>     are made (3).
>
> [image: Scheduled Actions]